CUDA unsupported MSVC
In 13.3.1.0, CreateLibrary[{demoFile}, "demo", "Compiler" -> NVCCCompiler] produces this error:
CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error:
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\include\crt/host_config.h(164): fatal error C1189:
#error:  -- unsupported Microsoft Visual Studio version!
Only the versions between 2017 and 2022 (inclusive) are supported!
The nvcc flag '-allow-unsupported-compiler' can be used to override this version check;
however, using an unsupported host compiler may cause compilation failure or incorrect run time execution.
Use at your own risk.

OK I am ready to take the risk, but how?
nvcc --version returns
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_17:51:05_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.3, V12.3.103
Build cuda_12.3.r12.3/compiler.33492891_0

Unfortunately I could not figure out how to obtain information about my MSVC installation

Go to the start menu, and begin typing x64 Native Tools ... and also run CUDACCompilers[] in Mathematica.

@flinty thank you! From x64 Native Tools I get Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.10.6 and from CUDACCompilers[] in Mathematica I get {}

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78576792/1136667
